# MATLAB GPU Parallel Loops Error: Error caught during construction of remote parfor code

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

So I have been trying to run a parfor loop containg GPU arrays and the following error pops up even though MATLAB computes the result. I have read about a similar error occurring when the size of the data passed is huge, however, each array here has 500 ints and just to be sure I tried reducing the size of the array to 100 and still the same thing occurs furthermore, I tried running this without the use of parfor and it works fine.

> Warning: Error caught during construction of remote parfor code.
>      The parfor construct will now be run locally rather than on the remote parallel pool. 
>      The most likely cause of this is an inability to send input arguments 
>      to the workers because of a serialization error. 
>      The error report from the caught error is:
>
> No method 'acquireLabs' with matching signature found for class
>      'com.mathworks.toolbox.distcomp.pmode.ParforControllerImpl'.
>
> Error in distcomp.remoteparfor (line 72)
>                      obj.NumWorkers = p.acquireLabs(int32(maxLabsToAcquire));
>
> Error in parallel_function>iMakeRemoteParfor (line 1060)
>      P = distcomp.remoteparfor(pool, W, @make_channel, parfor_C);
>
> Error in parallel_function (line 444)
>              [P, W] = iMakeRemoteParfor(pool, W, parfor_C);

My code is something like this...

```
parfor s = 1:part
   temp1 = temp_rand(s)<=p;

   temp3 = temp1-[0 temp1(1:end-1)];

   temp4 = update_part.*temp3;

   p_temp(s)=sum(temp4);

end;

p=p_temp+dist_div*temp5;
```

where apart from `dist_div` all are arrays of 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a problem in the implementation of `parfor` when the loop range is a `gpuArray`. You can work around this by instead running

```
parfor s = 1:gather(part)
    ...
end
```